# NetworkManager 1.4.2-1 doesn't connect to college wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, gnome, archlinux

I'm still relatively new to Arch and have been trying to get a good system going. I installed Gnome on Xorg as a desktop manager and have been trying to configure it to what I need. The biggest issue so far is that the included NetworkManager will not connect to my college's wifi. Here's some details about the network:

```
Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
CA certificate: none
EAP method: PEAP
Phase 2 authentication: MSCHAPv2
```

and then a username and a password. I have tried a bunch of different network managers (wpa_supplicant, netctl, and NetworkManager) but none of them have worked so far.

Here is the wpa_supplicant config file I tried to use (which didn't work):

```
network={
    ssid="NameOfTheNetwork"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    identity="MyUsername"
    password="MyPassword"
}
```

Here is the netctl config file, which also didn't work:

```
Interface=wlp3s0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa-configsection
IP=dhcp
IP6=stateless
WPAConfigSection=(
    'ssid="KSU"'
    'key_mgmt=WPA-EAP'
    'eap=PEAP'
    'anonymous_identity="MyUsername"'
    'identity="MyUsername"'
    'password="MyPassword"'
    'phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"'
)
```

and finally, here's the NetworkManager config file:

```
[ipv6]
method=auto

[connection]
id=NameOfTheNetwork
uuid=9e123fbc-0123-46e3-97b5-f3214e123456
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
auth-alg=open

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=SSID
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=0A:12:3C:DA:C1:A5
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=MyUsername
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password=MyPassword

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

None of these have worked, even though connecting to other networks (such as my room wifi, or my phone's mobile hotspot) has been very easy. I would really appreciate any help I could get on this, I haven't been able to find any way to reliably connect yet and I've been looking for a while.

Comment: Is it eduroam ? Cause if it's i think there's a part about it in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

With the description of your network, here's a working netctl config. Just change the YOUR_ with your networks informations.

```
Description='YOUR_PROFILE_DESCRIPTION'
Interface=YOUR_WIRELESS_INTERFACE_NAME
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa-configsection
IP=dhcp
ESSID=YOUR_UNIVERSITY_SSID
WPAConfigSection=(
        'ssid="YOUR_UNIVERSITY_SSID"'
        'proto=RSN'
        'key_mgmt=WPA-EAP'
        'pairwise=CCMP'
        'group=CCMP'
        'eap=PEAP'
        'identity="YOUR_UNIVERSITY_USERNAME"'
        'password="YOUR_UNIVERSITY_PASSWORD"'
        'phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try nmcli?

alias wifi="nmcli dev wifi"
alias wific="nmcli dev wifi connect"

wific NETWORKNAME password PASSWORD123

Answer (score 0):

I'd not connect to the PEAP+MSCHAPv2 network without certificate verification.
It is vulnerable to the MITM attack.

You'd better provide logs from wpa_supplicant with -dd flags.

Here is more details about my issues with eduroam.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211619